# Объединить два обновляемых листа Google Таблиц

Tags: google-spreadsheet, таблицы

У меня есть два обновляемых листа Google Таблиц, в которые импортируются ответы из двух разных Google Форм, сами формы идентичные по своим вопросам, т. е. формат строк на этих двух листах одинаков.  Есть ли какой-нибудь способ свести информацию с этих листов в один лист?

Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы можно обратится в [документацию](https://blog.google/products/g-suite/g-suite-pro-tips-how-sync-one-spreadsheet-another-google-sheets/) от гугл. Один из вариантов, это использование формулы)) Для этого берете url таблицы которую хотите использовать для вставки в другую таблицу и вставляете в данную [формулу](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en):

```
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123", "sheet1!A1:C10")

IMPORTRANGE(A2,"B2")
```

Описание синтаксиса `IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, range_string)`:

1. `spreadsheet_url` - урл таблицы которую хотите скопировать
2. `range_string` - то что вы хотите скопировать из этой таблицы.

Так же [вот](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/08/22/google-sheets-ways-to-combine-multiple-sheets/) есть интересная статья по вашему вопросу.